# RGBD-Slam crash using StereoSetup

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have problems running RGBD-Slam with a stereo camera. I wrote my own Stereo Matching Node which publish without any problems the Image and PointCloud2 Topic.

I added the Topics to the launch file:

But when I start RGBD-Slam the process dies:
REQUIRED process [rgbdslam-1] has died!
process has died [pid 15872, exit code -11, cmd ../ROS_Workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/bin/rgbdslam __name:=rgbdslam __log:=/../.ros/log/bea44dbc-d335-11e2-9c6f-406186ad7db0/rgbdslam-1.log].
log file: /../.ros/log/bea44dbc-d335-11e2-9c6f-406186ad7db0/rgbdslam-1*.log
Initiating shutdown!

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64914/rgbd-slam-crash-using-stereosetup/) by [Waterplanto](https://answers.ros.org/users/5124/waterplanto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My first guess would be that the point cloud needs to be structured, i.e. have width and height like the image.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0